# Angular customFilter function running twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to filter an array using a custom filter in angular.

Basically I have a binding as such: `{{ myData.winners | getWinnerString }}` that returns an array of items of any length between 1-4. If the array length is longer than 1, I'd like to return a custom string such as "Two way tie", "Three way tie", etc based on the array length. If it's just 1, I'd like to return the winner as is. This is what I have:

```
.filter('getWinnerString', function() {
    return function(array) {
        console.log(array);
        return array;
    }
});
```

When I run this, its looping through the array twice and logging the array twice. Any ideas as to why? Also any help/direction in actually setting up this function to return the correct string is greatly appreciated, as everything I've tried so far hasn't worked.

Comment: http://teropa.info/blog/2013/11/03/make-your-own-angular-part-1-scopes-and-digest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the `length` of the array and return your results strings based the comparison.

```
if (winners.length === 1) {
    return winners[0]; // return the only winner
} else {
    return numberString(winners.length) + " way tie";
}
```

Filters in angular are just a nicer way to transform/filter date in the template. Think of it as a function with one argument `writeOutWinnerString(winners)`.

Comment: What is numberString..is that a javascript function?

Comment: No, this is a function that maps your numbers 1,2,3,4 to strings ["One,"Two"...], but that should't be to difficult. I just took it as a shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly `filters` are executed every time there is an `$scope` `$digest`. So, as your application grows it may execute a lot more than that.

I found this link that my help you understand how filter execution works:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2489-How-Often-Do-Filters-Execute-In-AngularJS.htm